# linux perf error when adding a probe with arguments

Tags: ruby, linux, performance, perf

I'm trying to add a probe to ruby and it works fine without arguments:

`perf probe -x $(command -v ruby) --add 'vm_search_method.isra.0'`

When I list the available arguments I see:
`perf probe -x $(command -v ruby) --vars=vm_search_method.isra.0`

```
        @<rb_dtrace_setup+320>
                VALUE   obj
                VALUE   recv
                struct rb_call_cache*   cc
                struct rb_call_info*    ci
        @<rb_eql_opt+320>
                VALUE   obj
                VALUE   recv
        @<rb_equal_opt+272>
                VALUE   obj
                VALUE   recv
        @<vm_search_method+0>
                VALUE   recv
                struct rb_call_cache*   cc
        @<opt_eq_func+288>
                VALUE   obj
                VALUE   recv
                struct rb_call_cache*   cc
                struct rb_call_info*    ci
```

I want to get the id, which is a 64 bit unsigned long, from the `rb_call_info` struct:

```c
struct rb_call_info {     
    /* fixed at compile time */     
    ID mid;     
    unsigned int flag;     
    int orig_argc;     
};
```

so I try to add a probe:

`perf --debug verbose=10 probe -x $(command -v ruby) --add 'vm_search_method.isra.0 ci->mid:u64'`

```
probe-definition(0): vm_search_method.isra.0 ci->mid:u64
symbol:vm_search_method.isra.0 file:(null) line:0 offset:0 return:0 lazy:(null)
parsing arg: ci->mid:u64 into type:u64 ci, mid(1)
1 arguments
....
lazy:(null)
Open Debuginfo file: /usr/local/bin/ruby
Try to find probe point from debuginfo.
Opening /sys/kernel/tracing//README write=0
An error occurred in debuginfo analysis (-2).
  Error: Failed to add events. Reason: No such file or directory (Code: -2)
```

Any idea why this doesn't work? I'm not sure what file it's complaining doesn't exist, `/sys/kernel/tracing/README` is present.